# How to get the total number of rows with particular value in json file in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a JSON file which I am using for visualization using d3.js. I want to get the count of total rows for a particular code. I am using the following for doing so:

```
data.keys(d.code).length
```

But its not working. How can I solve this?
I have found one idea but it is not showing correct values. Whats the wrong with it?

```
Object.keys(d.code).length
```

I have a JSON file with following sample data

```
[
{"name":"a","code":20},
{"name":"b","code":20},
{"name":"c","code":20},
{"name":"d","code":21}

]
```

My target is to get the count of data with same code. For example for code 20 I should get 3 as output.

Comment: Can you be more specific, e.g. by including an example?

Comment: Ok let me do more explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need D3.js for this. Simple JavaScript should do it. Something like:

```
total = data.reduce(function(count, entry) { 
    return count + (entry.code === 20 ? 1 : 0);
}, 0);
```

Obviously, you can convert it to a function to handle arbitrary values other than 20.

Comment: Actually I don't know what will be the value of code. It needs not to be 20. It can be any value. Its actually continuously coming from hadoop.

Comment: So, like I said, convert the above fragment into a function.

Comment: Yap I got the idea. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You might as well use `d3.nest()` to group your data based on `code` and have it return the number of entries per group:

```js
var json = [
    {"name":"a","code":20},
    {"name":"b","code":20},
    {"name":"c","code":20},
    {"name":"d","code":21}
];

var nest = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) { return d.code; })
  .rollup(function(values) { return values.length; })
  .entries(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var count = 0;
var length = data.length;

for (var x = 0; x < length; x++)
{
    if (data[x].code == 20)
        count++;
}

console.log('Final count: ' + count);
```

Probably something like that.

If you want a function you could use this:

```
var getCount = function(data, val)
{
    var count = 0;
    var length = data.length;

    for (var x = 0; x < length; x++)
    {
        if (data[x].code == val)
            count++;
    }

    return count;
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
var count = getCount(data, 20); // should return 3
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I am looking for a smart solution that will make the code efficient'

Comment: Alright, what do you get with `console.log(data);`? In other words, what is data? Is it an array?

Comment: Also, keep in mind that more lines of code does not necessarily equate to less efficient code. It is quite often the opposite.

Comment: Can you please have my update to further get my goal?

Comment: Actually I don't know what will be the value of code. It needs no be 20. It can be any value. Its actually continuously coming from hadoop.

Comment: So you want to get the count of rows for each different code? So with your example data, you would want a count of 21 and a count of 20?